# Is there a closed formula for this heat equation with time dependent term

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

P(t,x) is in $c^2$, and f(t) is a time dependent polynomial. Here we just consider $x \in R$ does the following heat equation have closed formula?

$P_t$ = $P_{xx}$ + $f(t)P_x$

If yes, could you tell me where I can find it?

Answer (score 7):

Introduce new independent variables $T=t$, $X=x+\int f(t)dt$. Then your equation becomes nothing but the standard heat equation
$$
P_T=P_{XX}.
$$
You can take the formula for general solution of this equation and transform it back to your case using the inverse change of variables $x=X-\int f(T)dT$,  $t=T$.

Of course, all of this works for an arbitrary smooth $f$  (not necessarily a polynomial).